# Custom Password Saving with Devise Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have a form to edit user's profile. Im using device gem for login and other stuffs.

Thing is i want to make a new custom controller method just to save password..

this is so far what i have done

```
<%= form_for current_user, url: '/custom_update', html: {class: "form validate-form", novalidate: "novalidate", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Password</label>
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off", class: "form-control", placeholder: "Leave as blank if you don't want to change password", value: "" %>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and in controller

```
  def set_first_time_password
    p "=============="
    p params
    p "=============="
  end
```

and the params are coming as such.. that is passwords are shown on server.. its is not coming like password = [FILTERED].. and also how to save this password. I have devise gem. Please help. Im new to devise

Answer (score 0):

**This can be done to acheive the goal:**

```
@user = current_user
@user.update(params[:user][:password])
```